# Find Out What Rows Where Deleted And Updated

Tags: postgresql, netezza

Is it possible to somehow find out primary keys of rows deleted from a table?

Similarly, is it possible to find out primary keys of rows updated in a table?

Let's consider a simple use case:

I have two timestamps:

- start
- end

Give me primary keys of all rows updated/deleted between those two timestamps.

There is no information inside the tables to indicate they have been updated.

Comment: what are the possible values of primary keys? if those are serials than you can write query to find missing primary keys from start to end , and the resulting output are the rows which are deleted.

Comment: Postgres does not store that information about table activity, the best way would be to create a trigger yourself that either updates a row on the table for an update, or just writes the information to another location on an update or delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL doesn't provide anything like that built-in.

To do so it'd have to waste space and I/O keeping track of something most people will never need.

If your primary keys are contiguous and monotonic then you can just do a left anti-join over `generate_series` to find holes. However, this won't work if you're using `serial` (i.e. a sequence) to generate keys, because any rollback will create a gap even though nothing was really ever inserted in order to then be deleted.

You'll need to add an audit trigger to record the actions you want to track to a separate audit table. You can't do this retroactively; you can't audit things that're already in the past. This is the easiest option by far.

Another common solution is to flag rows as "deleted" at the application level, without actually deleting them from the table. For example, you might set a `deleted_at` and `deleted_by` field in the table. You can even make this application-transparent using a view with an `ON INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE DO INSTEAD` trigger.

There's also a `pg_audit` extension in development to make this easier, but it's not ready yet.

---

*Semi-relevant side-note*: In PostgreSQL 9.5 I think this might actually be possible for *recently* deleted rows, before `VACUUM` cleans them up, using a C extension. 9.5 will be capable of recording the timestamp of a commit, which 9.4 and below don't (they just record the transaction ID). So you could find out which transaction ID deleted a row by examining `xmax` and from there, determine the timestamp it was deleted at. You'd need a C extension because you'd have to do a "dirty read" on the table.

Comment: "If your primary keys are contiguous and monotonic then you can just do a left anti-join over generate_series" did the trick for me. 

My use case was to determine what rows were deleted in a source DB table so that I could delete the corresponding records in a destination DB table.  

The 2 tables must be different DBs for my use case, and rows in the destination DB's table all have a back-reference to the source DB table row ID.

It doesn't matter in this use case if I get a few extra IDs each time, since the alternative is bringing all remaining source IDs into memory.  

THANKS!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `Netezza` it is possible to not just pull the primary key but all the data that was deleted.

First run a command to expose the deleted records
`set show_deleted_records=true;`

Then query the database.

```
Select deletexid,*
 from table_name
 where deletexid>0
```

This trick is useful for reverting back mistakes.  Please note that deleted records are no longer persisted after a `reclaim` or `groom`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PostgreSQL can return data from modified rows (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) using RETURNING clause.

In the example from the question the correct query would be like:

```sql
  DELETE FROM products
  WHERE created_at > 'start' AND create_at < 'end'
  RETURNING id;
```

I know that question is too old but maybe it would be useful for somebody who happens to visit this page